# Export QTABLEWIDGET's data (Columns, rows , everything, ...) to SQLITE3

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Export `QTableWidget`s Data populated by the user to the db file. (the db file doesn't exist so SQLITE3 will create it` in the cited Directory.)

Here's the code I used :

```
    self.CreateDatasetButton.connect(self.createDS)

def CreateDS(self):
    self.proceed = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
        self, 
        'Information', 
        'Have you Verified your Data?',
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes|QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
    if self.proceed == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.showDialog()
    else:
        pass

def showDialog(self):
    self.text, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Almost Done !', 
        '\n\nname your file :')
    if ok:
        self.Createdb()

def Createdb(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('__Datasets__/%s.db' %(self.text))
    # problema here
    conn.close()
    self.app_statusbar.showMessage('%s is created' %(self.text()))
```

[image]

Comment: change `ok, self.text = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Almost Done !', 
        '\n\nname your file :')`  to `self.text, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Almost Done !', 
        '\n\nname your file :')`

Comment: that worked, 1 problem down. Thank you !

Comment: everything == all the information inside the QTableWidget.( Headers, items, ... )

Comment: the same logic as pandas, where the headers are the keys and the items are the value for example. example_dict = {"header name" : [item1, item2, item3, ....], }

Comment: i know i have a communication problem so just bear with me please

Comment: @eyllanesc noted.

Comment: @eyllanesc can you explain that code for me please ?

Comment: @user10567350 please if you ask about my solution, do it in the section below my answer as it was and I do not know why you deleted it.

Comment: @eyllanesc i couldn't tag you

Comment: @user10567350 the tag is used when there are more than 2 different users, here are 3 users: you, S.Nick and me, so if you write, who will notify? it is not known that using the tag can discriminate, it is the case that we are 2 there is no need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas the task is simple, the solution is to convert the QTableWidget to a dataframe and then export it:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.create_data()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Export")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    def create_data(self):
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(10)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["A", "B", "C", "D"])

        import random
        for i in range(self.table_widget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.table_widget.columnCount()):
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(random.randint(0, 100)))
                self.table_widget.setItem(i, j, it)

    def on_clicked(self):
        proceed = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 
            'Information', 
            'Have you Verified your Data?',
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes|QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if proceed != QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            return

        filename, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Almost Done !', 'name your file :')
        if ok:
            self.saveToDb(filename, "table_name")

    def saveToDb(self, db_filename, tablename):
        d = {}
        for i in range(self.table_widget.columnCount()):
            l = []
            for j in range(self.table_widget.rowCount()):
                it = self.table_widget.item(j, i)
                l.append(it.text() if it is not None else "")
            h_item = self.table_widget.horizontalHeaderItem(i)
            n_column = str(i) if h_item is None else h_item.text()
            d[n_column] = l

        df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        engine = sqlite3.connect(db_filename)
        df.to_sql(tablename, con=engine)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @user10567350 It would be good to analyze the solution and when you do not understand you can ask me about a specific problem, in the following comment I will try to explain it in a generic way.

Comment: @user10567350 The strategy is to obtain a dictionary of lists, where the key is the name of the column and the list has the values associated with the items under each column. To get the QTableWidgetItem I have used an item, but in the general case the items can be null so I check, if it is then I keep an empty string, if it is not I save the text. After creating the list dictionary creates a dataframe and export it to sqlite (these 2 steps I think you should know it since you mentioned the pandas)

Comment: @user10567350 Any other questions? If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: Yes , i have a question. Why the return of the QinputDialog is empty ?

Comment: @user10567350 Why do you say that QinputDialog is empty?

Comment: no i am sorry, i'm talking about the QMessageBox  ||  if proceed != QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            return || ( your coding is advanced for my level ) and why != and not == ?

Comment: @user10567350 If the user indicates that he does not want to do something so that he will continue doing things, it is better to leave the function using return, do not you think? This way we avoid having many nested if having a more readable code, unless you want to do something when the user says no. Do not forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: yes your point is correct, i have just tried your code, and it does create a file but with no extension, is that normal ?

Comment: @user10567350 in the dialog you must place the extension, for example mydb.db. Have you done it?

Comment: i am starting to get a grip of your code, what is the use of : 1) -- " table_name " in self.savetodb( filename,  " table_name ") ||| 2)-- tablename in def savetodb (self, db_filename, tablename ) |||

Comment: @user10567350 Do you know anything about pandas ?, I assume that as you commented you must know how to use to_sql(), that requires the name of the table, and just "table_name" is the name of the table you use by default.

Comment: i haven't reached that point yet but thank you for letting me know :D, anyway your code is perfect, and thank you for your help