# In Python: Insert all Entries in a QtableWidget into Database Table at once

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

wonder if someone knows how to insert with python all entries of a qtablewidget into a database. So far i found this coding:

```
# Creating a query for later execution using .prepare()
insertDataQuery = QSqlQuery()
insertDataQuery.prepare(
    """
    INSERT INTO contacts (
        name,
        job,
        email
    )
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    """
)

# Sample data
data = [
    ("Joe", "Senior Web Developer", "joe@example.com"),
    ("Lara", "Project Manager", "lara@example.com"),
    ("David", "Data Analyst", "david@example.com"),
    ("Jane", "Senior Python Developer", "jane@example.com"),
]

# Use .addBindValue() to insert data
for name, job, email in data:
    insertDataQuery.addBindValue(name)
    insertDataQuery.addBindValue(job)
    insertDataQuery.addBindValue(email)
    insertDataQuery.exec()
```

I am stuck in assigning the entries of a qtablewidget to data

Comment: You can find something useful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035570/export-qtablewidgets-data-columns-rows-everything-to-sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
# Ignore lazy imports
import sys
from typing import *

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

First, let's create a function that returns a `QTableWidget` with the data you provided:

[image: QTableWidget]

```
def createTable() -> QTableWidget:
    """Let's create a QTableWidget with the data you provided."""

    data = [
        ("Joe", "Senior Web Developer", "joe@example.com"),
        ("Lara", "Project Manager", "lara@example.com"),
        ("David", "Data Analyst", "david@example.com"),
        ("Jane", "Senior Python Developer", "jane@example.com"),
    ]

    table = QTableWidget()

    table.setRowCount(len(data))
    table.setColumnCount(len(data[0]))

    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        for j, val in enumerate(row):
            table.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(val))

    return table
```

Now we create a function to **fetch the data from the table** and return it in the same exact format:

```
def getData(table: QTableWidget) -> List[Tuple[str]]:
    """Fetch the data from the QTableWidget and return it as `data`."""

    data = []
    for row in range(table.rowCount()):
        rowData = []
        for col in range(table.columnCount()):
            rowData.append(table.item(row, col).data(Qt.EditRole))
        data.append(tuple(rowData))

    return data
```

For the db insert part, we can reuse the code you provided:

```
def insertData(data: List[Tuple[str]]) -> None:
    """Creating a query for later execution using .prepare()"""

    insertDataQuery = QSqlQuery()
    insertDataQuery.prepare(
        """
        INSERT INTO contacts (
            name,
            job,
            email
        )
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)
        """
    )
    # Use .addBindValue() to insert data
    for name, job, email in data:
        insertDataQuery.addBindValue(name)
        insertDataQuery.addBindValue(job)
        insertDataQuery.addBindValue(email)
        insertDataQuery.exec_()

    # Note that you need to run `QSqlDatabase().commit()`` if you want the data to be committed in the database.
```

Now putting it all together:

```
app = QApplication([sys.argv])

# Connect to sample database
sampleDb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
sampleDb.setDatabaseName("sample.sqlite")
sampleDb.open()


# Create table with sample data
table = createTable()

# Get data from table
data = getData(table)

# Insert data into the database
insertData(data)


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: hey thanks, that realy brought me a step further. only the last insertDataQuery.exec()
is not working. It says 
TypeError: exec(self, str): not enough arguments

Comment: Can you describe your problem better?

Comment: i have this coding:
        insertDataQuery = QSqlQuery()
        insertDataQuery.prepare(
            """
            INSERT INTO Test01 (
                Quantity,
                ProductId,
                Description,
                Price,
                Tax,
                NetTotal,
                GrossTotal
            )
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            """
        )
        
        data = getData(self.tableWidgetInvoiceItem)

Comment: for Quantity, ProductId, Description, Price, Tax, NetTotal, GrossTotal in data:
            insertDataQuery.addBindValue(Quantity)
            insertDataQuery.addBindValue(ProductId)
            insertDataQuery.addBindValue(Description)
            insertDataQuery.addBindValue(Price)
            insertDataQuery.addBindValue(Tax)
            insertDataQuery.addBindValue(NetTotal)
            insertDataQuery.addBindValue(GrossTotal)
            insertDataQuery.exec()     
            helper.conn.commit()

Comment: and at the  insertDataQuery.exec()  part it gives the error 
TypeError: exec(self, str): not enough arguments

Comment: Try `insertDataQuery.exec_()` instead of `insertDataQuery.exec()`

Comment: yes then the error disapears, but nothing is inserted to the database: I also commit afterwards: 
            insertDataQuery.exec_()     
            con.commit()
            con.close()

Comment: Can you print `insertDataQuery.lastError()` after `insertDataQuery.exec_()`?

Comment: it says
<PyQt5.QtSql.QSqlError object at 0x0000027016F54200>

Comment: Sorry, use `insertDataQuery.lastError().text()`

Comment: Are you sure you are using `QSqlDatabase().commit()`  after the insert? That is really strange behavior.

Comment: i created this:         con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QODBC")
        con.setDatabaseName("C:/Users/Egon/Documents/Invoice/Invoice.accdb")
and then:  con.commit()

Comment: this is the strange part:
con.setDatabaseName("C:/Users/Egon/Documents/Invoice/Invoice.accdb")
i can put any name it works. So i is not considering it

Comment: i opened a new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298243/python-insert-data-from-qtable-widget-into-ms-access-with-qsqldatabase